# Open CSV with native QGIS Widget

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv

I am writing a plugin that offers to open a CSV. I know the local path to the CSV but I don't know if it contains spatial data nor which name the `X` and `Y` could have.

The best way I can think of, is to utilize [the QGIS Delimited Text Widget](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgisapp.cpp#L3690-L3703) and set the path to the file, so it is possible to choose `X` and `Y` (if existing) from the native dialog (and use the other functions if needed).

My only problem is, that I can't find a way to set the path to the file inside the widget. Is there a way I can do this?

The code to open the widget:

```py
delimited_dlg = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().selectWidget("delimitedtext", self.main_win)  # use iface.mainWindow() in console

QObject.connect(delimited_dlg, SIGNAL( "addVectorLayer( QString, QString, QString )" ),
           self.main_win, SLOT( "addSelectedVectorLayer( QString, QString, QString )" ) )

delimited_dlg.show()
```

The native Class [QgsDelimitedTextSourceSelect](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/delimitedtext/qgsdelimitedtextsourceselect.cpp) uses the variable `txtFilePath` to store the path and the Class [QgsDelimitedTextProvider](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/delimitedtext/qgsdelimitedtextprovider.cpp) takes the `const QString& uri` as argument. Is there any chance I could set those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the neatest way of doing things, but you can achieve what you want by running this code into the QGIS Python console:

```
delimited_dlg = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().selectWidget("delimitedtext", iface.mainWindow())
delimited_dlg.children()[1].children()[2].setText("/path/to/your/csv_file.csv")
delimited_dlg.show()
```

`delimited_dlg` is the dialog, which contains children. Second child is a `QWidget`, which in turns contains some `QLabels` and `QLineEdits`, among other widgets. The `QLineEdit` widget you want is the third widget of the aforementioned `QWidget`, and we know we can set a `QLineEdit` using `setText()`, so we use it.

That's it!